# OS X location aware networking

Tags: macos, networking, dhcp, static-ip

I have a macbook running OS X 10.6.2. I would like to be able to use DHCP when roaming, but automatically switch to a static IP when my macbook is in range of my home router. Right now I must manually switch between network locations in order to use either the static or DHCP settings.

Unfortounately DHCP IP address reservation, which would solve this problem nicely, is not an available option on my router (Linksys WRT54G v8).

Comment: Wow, I couldn't believe that the WRT54G doesn't support IP address reservation (infinite IP leases), but you're right... http://linksys.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/linksys.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=3998

Comment: You can trade it in for a GL and flash it with Tomato which will do everything you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/), you can configure just about anything depending on your location, including network settings.

Comment: Yep, for me it's the best thing about having a Mac!

Comment: That program is awesome, I can't believe I never heard of it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out as soon as I get a chance -- there seems to be a problem with the wifi settings using snow leopard but there is a patch at http://groups.google.com/group/marcopolo-discuss/msg/616aaea242c8ba8d for anyone interested.